# Docker Build Issue - Stuck At Exporting Layers

Tags: docker

I am simply adding a user, group and directory into a standard image. It works fine until the userid number gets too big and then dock gets stuck exporting layers.I simplified the docker file down to:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy

USER root

RUN groupadd -r -g 996600555 testGroup
RUN useradd -u 997690599 -g testGroup -r -d /tmp/test testUser
RUN mkdir /tmp/test
RUN chown -R testUser:testGroup /tmp/test
RUN chmod -R g+rw /tmp/test

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The build output show:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 309B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy                                                                                                                             1.3s
 => CACHED [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy@sha256:ff753441e51d0260f917710d0dfdea73f698624768db2b31be3f6685b4953874                                                                0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy@sha256:ff753441e51d0260f917710d0dfdea73f698624768db2b31be3f6685b4953874                                                                       0.0s
 => [2/6] RUN groupadd -r -g 996600555 testGroup                                                                                                                                                            0.5s
 => [3/6] RUN useradd -u 997690599 -g testGroup -r -d /tmp/test testUser                                                                                                                                    0.6s
 => [4/6] RUN mkdir /tmp/test                                                                                                                                                                               0.6s
 => [5/6] RUN chown -R testUser:testGroup /tmp/test                                                                                                                                                         0.6s
 => [6/6] RUN chmod -R g+rw /tmp/test                                                                                                                                                                       0.6s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                    163.4s
 => => exporting layers
```

UPDATE:

- Without the added lines for adding user, group, and directory...image size is 454 MB
- If I change the value of group and userid to be 10000...image size is 457 MB
- If I change the value of group and userid to be 1000000...image size is 778 MB
- If I change the value of group and userid to be 5000000...image size is 2.07 GB
- If I change the value of group and userid to be 10000000...image size is 3.69 GB

As the userId gets increased, the processing time and size of images gets much larger.

Unfortunately, I need to stick with the large userId value to match up container and host user.Does anyone have a solution for this type of error?

DOCKER VERSION INFORMATION

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.28
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:09:02 2022
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.11.0 (83626)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:23 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.6
  GitCommit:        10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.2
  GitCommit:        v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: You can find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671214/docker-image-size-for-different-user

Answer (score 7):

I got lucky googling and figured out that if I add a `-l` option to my useradd command, per [this suggestion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5419#issuecomment-41478290), I overcome this issue. Same option could work for anyone so change the Dockerfile line that contains useradd command as :

```bash
RUN useradd -l -u 997690599 -g testGroup -r -d /tmp/test testUser
```